# How to change a cookie in js that has been set by php?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have that PHP code

```
$_COOKIE["regionid"] = 10;
```

When region select list is changed, I want to change the value of the`$_COOKIE["regionid"]` in js

like :

```
<select id="region" onChange="ChangeTheCookieValue(event)">
...
</select>
function ChangeTheCookieValue(event) {
}
```

How can JS read and change a PHP set cookie ?

Answer (score 2):

The origin of a cookie is irrelevant. The only thing that determines whether a cookie is accessible to Javascript is whether it has the HTTP_ONLY flag set.

The most basic way to change a cookie is

```
document.cookie = "regionid=whatever"
```

If you want to set flags, paths, expiration date etc, the syntax is somewhat more complicated.

Comment: that does really help me... How to change the value of that cookie ?

Comment: @user I just added an example.